# Numeric substrings between dots

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to make a regex that finds substrings that start with a dot (.), have only numbers and end either with another dot or it's the strings end.
To clarify, here are a few examples:

```
abc.123.ds => 123
aAsd.12sd.SAs.32.asd.3123 => 32 and 3123
111.2e2 => no result
aaa.bbb.13.320.a => 13 and 320
```

I tried different approaches, this is the closest I cam to a result is `"^[.][0-9]+\.?$"` but it still fails.
Any tips would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `^[.][0-9]+\.?$` fails becaue `^` forces the pattern to match at the start of the string and `$` makes it match the end of string (the full string), and the `.?` at the end, when matched, will consume the `.` and will not let you match an overlapping number with a dot in front.

I suggest using lookarounds:

```
(?<=\.)[0-9]+(?=\.|$)
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3C%3D%5C.%29%5B0-9%5D%2B%28%3F%3D%5C.%7C%5Cr%3F%24%29&i=abc.123.ds%0D%0AaAsd.12sd.SAs.32.asd.3123%0D%0A111.2e2%0D%0Aaaa.bbb.13.320.a&o=m)

**Details**:

- `(?<=\.)` - there must be a `.` immediately to the left of the current position
- `[0-9]+`  - 1+ digits
- `(?=\.|$)` - there must be a `.` or end of string immediately to the right of the current location.

C#:

```
var res = Regex.Matches(str, @"(?<=\.)[0-9]+(?=\.|$)")
      .Cast<Match>()
      .Select(m => m.Value)
      .ToList();
```

Comment: Note that in the demo I am using `\r?` in front of `$` because the test string is a multiline string.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the begining of line anchor and do an alternative for the other:

```
\.[0-9]+(\.|$)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty simple using **capturing groups**:

```
int[] result = Regex.Matches("\.(\d+)\.?").Cast<Match>().Select(x=> int.Parse(x.Groups[2].Value)).ToList();
```

First group is your entire match

> \.(\d+)\.?

Second is first nested brace-closed expression

> \d+